# List Iterator not dereferenceable

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I've been working on a lowest cost algorithm for airports where the user enters the name of an airport, and then I run this algorithm to spit out all the destinations you can go to, and the lowest cost, including connecting flights. I use a list iterator to iterate through the reachable destinations from the source location, but after just one iteration, the code breaks and a message comes up telling me that the iterator is not dereferenceable. here is my code

```
//Finds minimum cost
void findPaths(std::string source)
{
    std::list<int> Reachable;
    int min = INTMAX_MAX;
    int lowestIndex = -1;
    bool existsInList = true;
    std::stack<std::string> connectingFlights;
    //Make arrays
    //Initialize costs to a high value so any value will be smaller
    int costs[MAX]{INTMAX_MAX};

    //Initialize paths to negative one so that we know there is no location
    int path[MAX]{ -1 };

    //Find where the source is
    int srcIndex = findOrInsert(source);

    //Put the costs into the array, leaving the high number for where there    is no path
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        costs[i] = priceEdges[srcIndex][i];
    }

    //Put the source index in places that have a path
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if (priceEdges[srcIndex][i] == 0)
        {
            path[i] = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            path[i] = srcIndex;
            Reachable.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    //If the list is empty, we are done;
    while (!Reachable.empty())
    {
        //Find the index that has the lowest value in costs
        for (std::list<int>::iterator it = Reachable.begin(); *it < Reachable.size(); it)
        {
            if (costs[*it] < min)
            {
                min = costs[*it];
                int lowestIndex = *it;
            }

            //Remove the index with the lowest value in costs
            Reachable.erase(it);

            //Save the previous cost to compare after a change may occur
            int prevCost = costs[lowestIndex];

            //Assign the value to the lowest cost it can find
            costs[lowestIndex] = FindMin(costs[lowestIndex], costs[srcIndex] + priceEdges[srcIndex][lowestIndex]);

            //If the price has changed
            if (prevCost != costs[lowestIndex])
            {
                path[lowestIndex] = srcIndex;
            }
            existsInList = std::find(Reachable.begin(), Reachable.end(), lowestIndex) != Reachable.end();
            if (!existsInList)
            {
                Reachable.push_back(lowestIndex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `int costs[MAX]{INTMAX_MAX};` only initializes the first element of `costs` with `INTMAX_MAX`, the remaining elements are initialized to `0`. Same goes for your other array.

Comment: also `INTMAX_MAX` is probably out of range for `int`. You meant `INT_MAX` but either way this is redundant because you assign value to all entries next anyway

Comment: That `for` loop looks seriously messed up. `it` makes no sense as a loop step; that doesn't do anything. Similarly, `*it < Reachable.size()` isn't how you check whether you've reached the end of the list. You're also unconditionally erasing the loop iterator inside the loop, while you still need the iterator.

Comment: `Reachable.erase(it);` should be `it = Reachable.erase(it);`, and the loop condition should be `it != Reachable.end()`

Comment: That helps a ton! Looking at all these corrections are silly mistakes, I'm glad you could help me see them. I have another error now, when I am using existsInList it is creating an infinite loop. here is what I'm talking about 'code'    //If the price has changed
    if (prevCost != costs[lowestIndex])
    {
     path[lowestIndex] = srcIndex;
    }
    existsInList = std::find(Reachable.begin(), Reachable.end(), lowestIndex) != Reachable.end();
    if (!existsInList)
    {
     Reachable.push_back(lowestIndex);
    }
   }

Answer (score 4):

Your `for` loop is just plain wrong.  You are dereferencing an iterator without validating that it is even valid, and you are comparing a *destination value* the iterator refers to against the *size* of the vector, which makes no sense since they are two completely different things.

You need to replace the loop with this instead:

```
for (std::list<int>::iterator it = Reachable.begin(); it != Reachable.end(); )
```

Or even this:

```
std::list<int>::iterator it = Reachable.begin();
while (it != Reachable.end())
```

Then, to satisfy the loop's stop condition, you need to change this line:

```
Reachable.erase(it);
```

To this instead:

```
it = Reachable.erase(it);
```

You are removing an item from the `list`, which invalidates the iterator, but you are never updating the iterator to point at the next item, so the code will have problems when it tries to dereference the iterator again.  `erase()` returns an iterator to the next item in the list following the item that is being removed.

Also, on this line:

```
int lowestIndex = *it;
```

You are declaring a new temp variable that goes out of scope immediately afterwards, so it is never used.  You have a previous `lowestIndex` variable declared at the start of the function that you are never assigning a value to after initialization, so it is always -1.  You need to remove the `int` from the assignment:

```
lowestIndex = *it;
```

Comment: That helps a ton! Looking at all these corrections are silly mistakes, I'm glad you could help me see them. I have another error now, when I am using existsInList it is creating an infinite loop. here is what I'm talking about 'code'    //If the price has changed
    if (prevCost != costs[lowestIndex])
    {
     path[lowestIndex] = srcIndex;
    }
    existsInList = std::find(Reachable.begin(), Reachable.end(), lowestIndex) != Reachable.end();
    if (!existsInList)
    {
     Reachable.push_back(lowestIndex);
    }
   }

Comment: @Dean that is what a debugger is for. Step through the code while it is running and see exactly what it is doing. You are modifying `Reachable` while you are still looping through it, adding new items to it, you are likely never reaching the end of the list. I think you need to take a step back and rethink your algorithm, and maybe break it up into smaller pieces that don't rely on one giant list and a single loop doing everything at one time.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> //Remove the index with the lowest value in costs
> Reachable.erase(it);
> ```

This is invalidating the iterator but the for loop performs `*it < Reachable.size()`, which dereferences the invalid iterator. Instead, should probably do.

```
it = Reachable.erase(it);
```

Furthermore, the `*it < Reachable.size()` should probably be replaced with `it != Reachable.end()`.

Lastly, the *increment* portion of your `for` loop should probably be empty since it's not doing anything. You could also use a while loop instead.

```
auto it = Reachable.begin();
while (it != Reachable.end())
{
    // ...

    it = Reachable.erase(it);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: That helps a ton! Looking at all these corrections are silly mistakes, I'm glad you could help me see them. I have another error now, when I am using existsInList it is creating an infinite loop. here is what I'm talking about 'code'    //If the price has changed
    if (prevCost != costs[lowestIndex])
    {
     path[lowestIndex] = srcIndex;
    }
    existsInList = std::find(Reachable.begin(), Reachable.end(), lowestIndex) != Reachable.end();
    if (!existsInList)
    {
     Reachable.push_back(lowestIndex);
    }
   }